# Running JUnit test multiple times gives different results

Tags: android, debugging, testing

I have a test case for my app which fills in the `TextView`s in an Activity and then simulates clicking the `Save` button which commits the data to a database. I repeat this several times with different data, call `Instrumentation.waitForIdleSync()`, and then check that the data inserted is in fact in the database. I recently ran this test three times in a row without changing or recompiling my code. The result each time was different: one test run passed and the other two test runs reported different data items missing from the database. What could cause this kind of behavior? Is it possibly due to some race condition between competing threads? How do I debug this when the outcome differs each time I run it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a race condition.
remember in the world of threading there is no way to ensure runtime order.

I'm not an android dev so I'm only speculating but UI is only on one event thread generally so when you call the method from another thread (your test) you're probably breaking that as you're outside of the event thread.

You could try using a semaphore or more likely a lock on the resource.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: Thanks for the links to the Lock and Semaphore classes. I will look into those. The Android additions to JUnit require that some of the methods used in my tests are run on the UI thread, such as simulating a button click. I guess I need to look into what other threads are also running. I suspect there is at least one more since I have to explicitly tell JUnit what tests (or parts of tests) are run on the UI thread.

Comment: And since my question is specific to Android, here are the Android docs for the [java.util.concurrent package](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 1):

I (finally!) found a solution to this problem. I now call `finish()` on the tested `Activity` to make sure that all of its connections to the database are closed. This seems to ensure consistency in the data when I run the assertions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a probe for the database data rather than a straight assert on it. By this I mean make a piece of code that will keep checking the database for up to a certain amount of time for a condition rather than waiting for x seconds (or idle time) then check, I am not on a proper computer so the following is only pseudo code

```
public static void assertDatabaseHasData(String message, String dataExpected, long maxTimeToWaitFor){
    long timeToWaitUntil = System.getCurrentTimeMillis() + maxTimeToWaitFor;
    boolean expectationMatched = false;
    do {
        if(databaseCheck() == dataExpected){
            expecttionMatched == true;
        }
    }while(!expectationMatched  && System.getCurrentTimeMillis() < timeToWaituntil);
    assertTrue(message, expectationMatched);
}
```

When i get to a computer i will try to relook into the above and make it better (I would actually of used hamcrest rather than asserts but that is personal preference)